# Writing unit tests that work with the DOM

Tags: dart

I have some functionality that works with the DOM, specifically dealing with resizing elements. I looked over the Unit Testing documentation [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/) and couldn't find anything on doing this.  Is it possible?  Is there any existing documentation that shows how to do it?

Comment: Do you want unit testing for javascript maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try DumpRenderTree - headless chrome which outputs a textual version of layout.

eg:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
layer at (0,0) size 808x820
  RenderView at (0,0) size 800x600
layer at (0,0) size 800x820
  RenderBlock {HTML} at (0,0) size 800x820
    RenderBody {BODY} at (8,8) size 784x804
      RenderHTMLCanvas {CANVAS} at (0,0) size 800x800 [bgcolor=#808080]
      RenderText {#text} at (0,0) size 0x0
#EOF
#EOF
```

Kevin Moore's blog post ["Headless Browser Testing with Dart"](http://work.j832.com/2013/01/headless-browser-testing-dart.html) explains the details (and the above snippet is taken from that)